# Blockchain compression Suggestions

Tags: blockchain, evm

I am planning to do a course project on block chain compression so that network transfer time is optimized. I read somewhere that the EVM bytecode component of the blockchain can be compressed. Is that the only low hanging fruit? Other suggestions are also welcome.

I read about [Merkelized Abstract syntax Trees](https://github.com/jl2012/bips/blob/mast/bip-mast.mediawiki)...I am wondering if Ethereum can benefit from those.

Just to add, I am also aware of state tree pruning. But I am looking for compressing blockchain so that network transfer time is saved (not necessarily the disk space, since it has to be decompressed on disk for space efficiency)